# Sharepoint 2010 Archiving Site

Tags: sharepoint, deployment

I have a Sharepoint site A and I want to move and update it to another site B along with it's structure and content; which can be done by content deployment but if the user deletes an item from site A it should not be deleted in site B.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but if you need to back up Site A and move the content/structure to site B, then I would recommend using powershell. This is assuming that this is a one time process. You can use:

Backup-SPSite -Identity "SITE A URL" -Path "C:\spsite.bak" -Force -Confirm:$False

Then after the back up is complete, run the following:

Restore-SPSite "SITE B URL" -Path C:\spsite.bak -Force -Confirm:$False

Now you have an exact replica of Site A in Site B, but changes on either site will not affect one another.

Comment: Thanks, changes on site A should be visible in site B except deletion of the contents.

Comment: Then you need a custom solution. Depending on the scope of the contents that need to be synched, the solution could be complex. You should include all this info in your original questions

Comment: I have included this info in my original q "but if the user deletes an item from site A it should not be deleted in site B".. Thanks for your response..